# What is an example of asymmetric cryptography?

Tags: public-key

What is an example of asymmetric cryptography or public key cryptography?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, your favorite search engine should bring up a truckload of examples and [our site here also contains ample pointers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-key). But just to have a ***canonical Q&A*** related to this…

First up, note that the fact you are currently viewing this website using a secure connection (HTTPS) indicates you are actively using a RealWorld™ example of asymmetric cryptography while you are reading this.

[image: screenshot showing secure connection]

But to give you a few more examples, here’s quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Examples for your convenience:

> **Examples of well-regarded asymmetric key techniques for varied purposes include:**
>
> - Diffie–Hellman key exchange protocol
> - DSS (Digital Signature Standard), which incorporates the Digital Signature Algorithm
> - ElGamal
> - Various elliptic curve techniques
> - Various password-authenticated key agreement techniques
> - Paillier cryptosystem
> - RSA encryption algorithm (PKCS#1)
> - Cramer–Shoup cryptosystem
> - YAK authenticated key agreement protocol
>
> **Examples of asymmetric key algorithms not widely adopted include:**
>
> - NTRUEncrypt cryptosystem
> - McEliece cryptosystem
>
> **Examples of notable – yet insecure – asymmetric key algorithms include:**
>
> - Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem
>
> **Examples of protocols using asymmetric key algorithms include:**
>
> - S/MIME
> - GPG, an implementation of OpenPGP
> - Internet Key Exchange
> - PGP
> - ZRTP, a secure VoIP protocol
> - Secure Socket Layer, now codified as the IETF standard Transport Layer Security (TLS)
> - SILC
> - SSH
> - Bitcoin
> - Off-the-Record Messaging